# How can i fill the other form fields automatically if user fill one field in jsp (while using spring mvc and hibernate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc and Hibernate. I have two entities "project" and employee and their is bidirectional one to many mapping between both. I am able to add existing employees in database to project. But i want now that when the user fills the form fields of employees in jsp, it automatically shows name of all the employees in drop down and when an employee is selected its other fields are automatically set. How can i do that. 
I'm novice in spring mvc and jquery.

my jsp to add employees to project

addEmployee.jsp

```
<form:form modelAttribute="employeeAttribute" method="POST" action="${Url}">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>ProjectId:</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="${projectId}" />
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="employeeId"></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="employeeId" type="hidden"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="employeeName">Employee Name:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="employeeName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="designation">designation:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="designation"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="department">department:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="department"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="password">password:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form:form>
```

corresponding action in controller after form is filled

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAdd(@RequestParam("id")Integer projectId,Model model){

    Employee emp = new Employee();

    model.addAttribute("projectId",projectId);
    model.addAttribute("employeeAttribute",emp);

    return "addEmployee";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAdd(@RequestParam("id")Integer projectId,@ModelAttribute("employeeAttribute")Employee employee) throws IOException{

    Employee emp = employeeService.getEmployeeByName(employee.getEmployeeName());
    if(emp==null){
        return "Error";
    }
    else{
        employeeService.add(projectId,emp);
        return "redirect:/project3/list";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the event for `onChange()` using javascript for the select box that contains the `user list` .Using ajax you can send the userid to your controller

So that you fetch the attributes associated with the user and put them in the `request` . On success of your ajax populate the fields with the appropriate values that are fetched from database.

some good startup examples [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007304/populate-listbox-options-with-result-of-an-ajax-call-using-query-in-spring-mvc-e).

Learn more about [jquery-ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)